# Cookie is empty in the console

Tags: cypress

**I am testing a website and on the payment page it gives me a checkout error and I realize that the cookie are empty in the console, what can I do?**
[image: error in the payment page]
[image: Cookie empty]

Comment: Cypress is clearing the cookies before each test per default. Maybe that is the root cause.

Comment: yes, but if that were the cause, it is deleting them with the test running

Comment: I have tested other sites that are the same as this one, but what they change is that they only have the iframe of the card on the payment page.  But on this site there are two separate iframes, the card and the cvv, I don't know if that has anything to do with it.